# International Language

Tags: language

I was reading [International Auxiliary Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_auxiliary_language), but I don't like their setups.

Because, mostly, they use Latin alphabets!

And that, my friends, cause confusions!

No matter what the letter was intended to be pronounced, EVERY country (especially those use uses Latin alphabets such as English, German, French, Spanish, etc.) WILL pronounce it in their own way!

'J' is pronounced 'h' in Spanish, 'z' in French, 'y' in German.

Many country also have different pronunciation for 'H' and 'R'.

Other than that, many countries are even "incapable of" pronouncing letters such as 'RR' in Spanish or 'Ü' in German!

Due to those drawbacks, the invented language bound to be less efficient than it was intended to be!

So, I was thinking, is there a way to overcome such drawbacks!?

First of all, the most obvious approach is to find a set of alphabets that "Nobody had in common"! At least, find those letters that are used by "only one country"! Such as some letters in Greek alphabets (As far as I know, Greek are the only country that use Greek alphabets).

Second, I think it's better to divide that alphabets into 2 group. First group are those letters that "every people in every country know how to pronounce". I think it's good to base it on Japanese, because Japanese has the least amount of pronunciations as far as I know. I believe they are the easiest language to learn pronunciation-wise.

This group of letters build up the "basic and conceptual words", where all other words are the "combination product" of these words. You can think it as the "building block" of the words.

Thus, I think it's better to make the words "a word a syllable" such as Chinese. And 1-syllable words made from the "Basic letters" are the "building block" of the words. More complicated words are the combination of these "basic conceptual words". Such as "Refrigerator" are actually "Electronic Ice Box" in Chinese.

I also think it's better to make the letters "phonetic"! 'A' is always pronounced 'a' NO MATTER WHAT! Unlike English, 'A' has 2 million ways of pronunciation!

The second group of letters are those pronunciations that "All the countries in the world that **COULD EVER MADE**! I know this might sounds like far fetching, but the idea is "Easy for everybody to learn such language. And for those who are familiar with the language, it will be easy for them to learn **EVERY LANGUAGE**"!

You can think it as "The first group letters are the intersection of the pronunciations of every language, and the second group are the union of the pronunciations of every language".

And the second group of letters are only used for those more advanced, probably grammatical, concepts. Which is "Unnecessary for basic conversations but critical for literature".

So, my question is:

> Is such ideas feasible!? What's the ups-and-downs, pros-and-cons of my ideas!? Did I miss something!? What else should I pay special attention to!?

Much appreciated!!!

Comment: I don't understand your angst. [IPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet) (the International Phonetic Alphabet, not the beer) is a thing. The pronunication of Esperanto, for example, is quite well-defined; even if in their native spelling a Frenchman would pronounce the letter "u" as `/y/` and a Spaniard would pronounce the letter "j" as `/x/`, the rules of Esperanto mandate that "u" be pronounced `/u/` and "j" be pronounced `/j/` and everybody who learns Esperanto learn this. People of different national backgrounds can and **do** communicate in Esperanto.

Comment: *"'J' is pronounced 'h' in Spanish, 'z' in French, 'y' in German":* you are wrong. The letter "j" is pronounced `/x/` in Spanish, `/ʒ/` in French and, surprise, `/j/` in German. In French, the sound (= phoneme in actual linguistic terminology) `/z/` is written either "s" (between vowels) or "z". In German the sound `/y/` is written "ü". Spanish doesn't use the phoneme `/h/` at all. The [International Phonetic Alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet) is your friend. Learn it.

Comment: I'm confused how one can learn a foreign language and not learn how to pronounce it. I can assure you that, for example, English is very widely used as a language for international communication and somehow we all understand each other, even if in my native language "ch" would be pronounced `/kʲ/` (realized as `[c]`)...

Comment: Is this a problem? In early modern Europe, Latin flourished as a "go-between" language for art and science even though speakers pronounced it differently based on their native languages. At the extreme, various Chinese languages are *only* mutually comprehensible in writing, but writing still allows for a degree of cross-language understanding.

Comment: For the comment which you correct my "pronunciation", I think we have a misunderstanding here! the "h, z, y" in my question is **NOT** IPA!!! It's just **English** that **REPRESENT** the sounds! And coincidentally, they just so happen to pronounce **THE SAME** as your "**CORRECTION**"! Well, at least close enough!

Comment: @Cadence: But everybody understood the Ecclesiastical pronuncation used by the Roman Church...

Comment: Since we are in the context of language, internet conventions say that bold and capital letters are used for shouting. Please lower your tone.

Comment: @L.Dutch I do apologize! It's not my intention to "shout"! I just try to "emphasize" it! It just my habit (probably a bad one)! Sorry!

Comment: @AlexP Understood, perhaps (except maybe those silly Anglicans) but that doesn't mean that it's what they would speak in a professional context.

Comment: @AlexP I'm sorry to keep opposing you! But apparently you haven't been around with many "foreigner people who speak other language than their mother tongue"! I do! Because, unfortunately and shamefully, I been to the joint! And I'm telling you, you would want to bang your head on the wall listening to them "foreigners" speaking English! Now I'm NOT 
depreciating them or anything! I'm just saying that people DO "pronounce words in their own pronunciation"!

Comment: @Cadence: The particularly strange English pronunciation of Latin is post-medieval. (What happened was the [Great English Vowel Shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Vowel_Shift), which is decidedly Early Modern.)

Comment: I am one of those foreigners who speak English *a lot* with lots of other foreigners. And it works. Humans have a very great tolerance to differences in pronunciations. (Fun anecdote: one the most difficult encounters with strange English pronunications was with a Texan who, for some reason, was using his native dialect instead of being polite and at least trying to switch to International English.)

Comment: @AlexP I never said that it would "NEVER WORK"! For those educated enough and dedicated enough, they could learn to speak "perfect" second language! I was just trying to say that "It cause confusions, or misleading, and therefore not for EVERYBODY"!

Comment: (a) This question has been asked in the wrong place.  It is clearly not a worldbuilding question but a question about repairing/improving an attribute of the real world.  VTC.  Please take this question to [conlang.se]. (b) This language was intentionally designed to accommodate the largest number of people as represented by languages and cultures on Earth today - *not everyone.*  There is no such thing as a second language everyone could learn quickly and efficiently or we'd all be speaking it.

Comment: @JBH I do apologize! But since Tim B II has already answered it, I can not remove it! I'll take your warning to heart in the future!

Comment: This question is much more suitable for [the invented languages stack](https://conlang.stackexchange.com).  We focus on worldbuilding here; they focus on languages over there!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**You're describing Hangul (the writing system for the Korean language) but there are issues.**

Hangul is a really cool writing system because it was designed from the ground up by the best linguists of the day at the request of the emperor of the Korean peninsula to solve very similar problems to the ones you describe. It's the ultimate nerd's writing system when you get right down to it and in theory you could extend it to almost any other language over time when you get all the consonants and vowels mapped.

But the real problem isn't the writing system; it's the spoken language. It drifts. The first published paper on this was in fact written by the youngest Grimm brother (Jacob IIRC; he was a scholar) that documented phonetic drift in a specific dialect of German. Subsequently, the idea that words change in their pronunciation over time as vowels and consonants are vocalised differently over that time has become known as Grimm's Law.

Additionally, we have new words coming in, old words dropping out, and the pronunciation of the words that stick around evolve despite how they are spelt. This is why many of the older words in English (like Knight) are not spelt the way they sound in the modern form of the language. Writing is static (comparitively at least). Sounds on the other hand change more often and can even change within a few short years under certain conditions.

Of course, even the alphabet can change over time. The reason why the J is pronounced in different ways by different languages that use the Latin alphabet is because the J isn't even an original Latin character; it was introduced by the Germans in around the 15th century (they were going through a real boost in their linguistic understanding around then) to cover off the use of I as a consonant in certain circumstances. This is why it sits after the I in the alphabet; it's effectively the 'other' I.

Bottom line is that language can, does, and must change to accommodate the needs of those speaking it. This is in the written form as well as the spoken form and as such while you could extend a written form like Hangul into a broader set of sound representations in how phonemes are used in the international arena, but your real problem will be maintaining it given the broad and sweeping changes that occur in vernacular languages all the time to cater for new concepts, ideas, change in the social environment, etc.

Comment: Hangul is utterly unsuitable for writing French, or English, or Romanian, or Russian. It is strongly wedded to the syllabic structure of Korean, for example. And I think that by "extended Hangul" you mean [IPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet).

Comment: @AlexP Hangul is, however, a useful case study in how this sort of constructed alphabet works in practice, and how the spoken language gradually slips away from it. Essentially it's saying "this was already tried, on a smaller scale, and it didn't work".